# Is it possible to create fragments manually with FragmentTabHost?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-tabs

`FragmentTabHost` in its usual configuration is courteous enough to handle the instantiation of fragments for us, meaning we just need to pass in the class, and it does the rest:

```
mTabHost.setup(this, getSupportFragmentManager(), R.id.realtabcontent);
mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("friends").setIndicator("Friends"), FriendsFragment.class, null);
mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("contacts").setIndicator("Contacts"), ContactsFragment.class, null);
```

As you can see, we simply need to pass in the `Fragment` classes (e.g. `FriendsFragment.class`) and the args bundle to be passed (in this case `null`) and the `FragmentTabHost` will handle the initialisation of the fragments for us. It also seems to be behave lazily and will only load the fragment when the tab is actually changed.

**This is great** in a lot of cases, but what I want to do is manually pre-create my fragments, and then attach them to the `FragmentTabHost` afterwards. The main advantage of this is that I can be sure that all of my tab fragments exist at all times, rather than being created lazily when the user changes tabs.

Ideally what I'd like to have is something like this (if only the method existed!):

```
FriendsFragment f1 = new FriendsFragment();
ContactsFragment f2 = new ContactsFragment();

mTabHost.setup(this, getSupportFragmentManager(), R.id.realtabcontent);
mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("friends").setIndicator("Friends"), f1);
mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("contacts").setIndicator("Contacts"), f2);
```

So the question is: is it possible to manually pre-create the fragments with `FragmentTabHost` or is it necessary to take a different approach entirely?

Comment: A lot of ways to do stuff, but only one of ways will work. Let the game begins. It appears it didn't, so you need to handle the interaction between fragment object and its creator on both sides by checking if it already exists.